# object to toString method in java with subclasses

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object, tostring

Yo! I have a task with subclasses, where I gotta use the printible version of output, and I added the method toString(), however it seems that the method doesn't really apply to some part of the code.I post all three classes for this task: Class 1

```
public class Prostokat {

    int szerokosc;
    int wysokosc;
    public Punkt origin;

    public Prostokat () {
        origin = new Punkt(0,0);
        szerokosc = 0;
        wysokosc = 0;
    }

    public Prostokat (Punkt p) {
        origin = p;
    }

    public Prostokat (Punkt p, int a){
        origin = p;
        szerokosc = a;
        wysokosc = a;   
    }

    public Prostokat (Punkt p, int szerokosc, int wysokosc) {
        origin = p;
        this.szerokosc = szerokosc;
        this.wysokosc = wysokosc;   
    }

    public Prostokat (int x, int y, int szerokosc, int wysokosc) {
        origin = new Punkt(x,y);
        this.szerokosc = szerokosc;
        this.wysokosc = wysokosc;
    }

    public int getSzerokosc() {
        return szerokosc;
    }

    public void setSzerokosc(int szerokosc) {
        this.szerokosc = szerokosc;
    }

    public int getWysokosc() {
        return wysokosc;
    }

    public void setWysokosc(int wysokosc) {
        this.wysokosc = wysokosc;
     }

    public Punkt getOrigin() {
        return origin;
    }

    public void setOrigin(Punkt origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    public  String toString(Prostokat c) {
        String res = "punkt: " + "(" + origin + ")" + "szerkosc: " + 
            szerokosc + "wysokosc: " + wysokosc;
        return res;
    }

    public int obwod(Prostokat c) {
        return 2*szerokosc + 2*wysokosc;
    }

    public int pole(Prostokat c) {
        return szerokosc*wysokosc;
    }

    public void setOrigin(int i, int j) {
        this.origin = origin;   
    }

    public void setPunkt(Punkt p) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }
}
```

Then class 2 for `Punkt`, where I also used this method:

```
package prostokatzadanie2;

public class Punkt {

    public int j;
    public int k;

    public Punkt(int j, int k) {
        this.j =j;
        this.k = k;
    }

    public Punkt (int m) {
        this.j =m;
        this.k = m;
    }

    public String toString(Punkt p) {
        String pim = j + "," + k;
        return pim;
    }
}
```

And then the main class, from where output should work:

```
package prostokatzadanie2;

public class zadanie2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Punkt p1 =new Punkt (1,5);
        Punkt p2 = new Punkt (2);
        Punkt p3 = new Punkt (18,6);
        Prostokat pr1 = new Prostokat();
        Prostokat pr2 = new Prostokat(p1,15);
        Prostokat pr3 = new Prostokat(p2,10,6);
        Prostokat pr4 = new Prostokat(0,75,10,4);
        System.out.println("pr1: " + pr1.toString(pr1));
        System.out.println("pr2: " + pr2.toString(pr2));
        System.out.println("pr3: " + pr3.toString(pr3));
        System.out.println("pr4: " + pr4.toString(pr4));
        System.out.println("==================================================");
        pr1.setWysokosc(26);
        pr1.setOrigin(5,96);
        pr2.setPunkt(p3);
        System.out.println("pr1: " + pr1.toString(pr1));
        System.out.println("pr2: " + pr2.toString(pr2));
        System.out.println("pr3: " + pr3.toString(pr3));
        int pr2Obwod = pr2.obwod(pr2);
        System.out.println("Obwod pr2: " + pr2Obwod);
        int pr3Pole = pr3.pole(pr3);
        System.out.println("Pole pr3: " + pr3Pole);
    }
}
```

So output is quite unreadable, which confuses me, where I might have forgotten to put the toString method correctly.
This is the output:

```
pr1: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@139a55)szerkosc: 0wysokosc: 0
pr2: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@1db9742)szerkosc: 15wysokosc: 15
pr3: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@106d69c)szerkosc: 10wysokosc: 6
pr4: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@52e922)szerkosc: 10wysokosc: 4
==================================================
pr1: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@139a55)szerkosc: 0wysokosc: 26
pr2: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@1db9742)szerkosc: 15wysokosc: 15
pr3: punkt: (prostokatzadanie2.Punkt@106d69c)szerkosc: 10wysokosc: 6
Obwod pr2: 60
Pole pr3: 60
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Are you trying to override `Object.toString`? If so, why have you added a parameter?

Comment: I don't know, probably I wanted to add a specific method to specific type of object because I thought that Eclipse wouldn't understand what I want to assign my method to. Eclipse is smarter than I thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrode `toString` incorrectly in both classes.  The [method to override in `Object` takes no parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

You don't use the parameter anyway, so just remove the parameter in both classes.

```
public String toString()
```

If you add the `@Override` annotation to methods that are intended to override or implement a method from a superclass or superinterface, then the compiler will generate an error for you on failure to override, giving you information you need to easily see that the method didn't actually override what you intended.

Comment: thanks! with override I don't need a parameter, however Eclipse didn't really make notification so it seemed to work just fine from the first glance. Anyway, thank you

Comment: It is legal to overload a method from a superclass or superinterface (which is what you did), so Eclipse won't flag it, even if it's not what you intended.  Also, as the asker of the question, at your discretion, you may [accept exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think helps you the best.

Comment: thanks, got it. yep, ofc, a must do thing here, i'm just not bothered smtimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Use tab Source -> Generate toString()... in eclipse and no problem!

The same advice about Generating Constructor using Fields, Getters and Setters them locates in the same tab on panel.

Comment: yep, generating getters and setters automatically, which is handy and must be with toString method.